# Given a real number $\lambda \in \Re$, compute $\int_0^1 x^\lambda \ln(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given a real number $\lambda \in \Re$, define $f_\lambda(x)=x^\lambda \ln(x)$

a) For each $\lambda \in \Re$, compute $\lim_{x\to0^+}f_\lambda(x)$

b) Determine for which values $\lambda \in \Re$ the integral $\int_0^1{x^\lambda \ln(x) dx}$ converges.

Not really sure what at all to do here, or what this is asking of me. We're learning about Infinite Series, Power Series, and determining convergence using ratio, root test, etc. Have not yet touched Taylor Series.

Comment: Do you know l'Hôpital's rule? It can be used to solve (a).

Comment: If you know $x\log x \to 0$, then for $\lambda > 0$, consider $\lambda x^\lambda \log x = x^\lambda \log(x^\lambda)$.  You also have to do $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda < 0$.

Comment: The title doesn't really explain what you are asking here. Please edit the title to be more clear e.g. "Studying the convergence of $\int_0^1x^\lambda\ln(x)~\mathrm dx$". It's important that the title be specific to what you are asking so that it can be easily found when others have similar questions. See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) for more details.

Comment: I have voted to close this question (and downvoted it) because it is phrased as an isolated question without further context.  You could improve this question by providing some additional context.  Where did this problem come from? Why are you interested in it?   What book are you working out of (assuming that you are working out of a book)?  For more information, read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: It is notable that you've mentioned "We're learning about Infinite Series, Power Series, and determining convergence using ratio, root test, etc. Have not yet touched Taylor Series." Usually I would consider this at least some context, but to be frank, I fail to see how any of that is relevant to the question. Add information related to the question and see the links above.

Comment: That would be why I am also confused. It doesn't seem relevant to anything we've learned so I'm not too sure where to start with this. @SimplyBeautifulArt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (a) the point is that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^\lambda = 0$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \ln(x) = - \infty$, and so we get a classic "indeterminate form." This means to compute the limit you need to use L'Hospitals rule.

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} x^\lambda \ln(x) &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{-\lambda}}\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{(\frac{d}{dx} \ln x)}{(\frac{d}{dx} x^{-\lambda})}\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{1/x}{-\lambda x^{-\lambda - 1}}\\
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x^\lambda}{-\lambda}\\
&=0
\end{align*}

When $\lambda \neq 1$, you can show that the integral converges using integration by parts in conjuction with part (a), which you need since it is an "improper integral." I'll leave the details to you.

When $\lambda = 1$, you can still use integration by parts to compute the integral, but in this case it diverges, since the indefinite integral is $$\int x^{-1}\ln(x) dx = \frac{(\ln x)^2}{2}+k,$$
which is easily checked by the chain rule:
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\frac{(\ln x)^2}{2}+k = \frac{2 \ln x}{2} \frac{d}{dx} \ln x = x^{-1}\ln x$$

Hope this helps, and good luck filling in the details!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Comment: you assume $\lambda \geq 0$, right?